# Fortran substitute subroutine name using macro

Tags: macros, fortran

I am writing a module that allows users to log information. I want to provide an interface that logs a string message, which can be called as

```
call m_log(msg)
```

So in file m_logger.f90, I will have

```
module m_logger
..
  subroutine m_log(msg)
  ..
end module
```

In file main.f90, a user will have

```
program main
use m_logger

call m_log(msg)
end program
```

Now how can I substitute `call m_log(msg)` with `call m_log(msg, __FILE__, __LINE__)` ?

Because of this substitution, a different subroutine `subroutine m_log(msg, filename, linenum)` in the logger module will be called instead.

If I use a macro like `#define m_log(msg) m_log(msg,__FILE__,__LINE__)` , it will have to be added to every user file that uses the logger.

Also, I do not want to enforce the user to pass `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` explicitly.

Is there a way I can do this? Or are there any other alternatives altogether?

Thanks in advance

Edit:
I had a discussion on comp.lang.fortran. Adding a link for reference.
[here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.fortran/Nl-lGjhdLAQ)

Comment: Can you add some clarifications or examples of what you are trying to achieve here?  I am confused.

Comment: basically how do i replace `m_log(msg)` with `m_log(msg,__FILE__,__LINE__)` automatically, maybe using a macro.

Comment: Where do the `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` comes in?  When you say you do not want the user to pass the arguments explicitly, do you mean the user will be defining them as environmental variables or macros instead of placing them in function calls?

Comment: `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` are compiler macros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case you would have to use the same approach C uses. Define the macro you proposed

```
 #define log(msg) m_log(msg,__FILE__,__LINE__)
```

in a separate file (possibly with other useful macros) and include it using `#include "file.inc"` (standard Fortran include won't suffice).

If the macro has a different name, than the subroutine it actually calls, you can ensure that the user has to use the include and cannot forget it.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to force `__file__` and `__line__` explicitly, then you can use the [optional](http://www.sdsc.edu/~tkaiser/f90.html#Optional%20arguments%20and%20intent) flag, such that your subroutine looks like:

```
subroutine m_log(msg, filename, linenum)
   character(len=*) :: msg
   character(len=*), optional :: filename
   integer, optional :: linenum
   if(present(filename)) then
      <something with filename>
   endif
   if(present(linenum)) then
      <something with linenume>
   endif
   <normal stuff with msg>
end subroutine
```

The intrinsic function [present](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/PRESENT.html) returns a true value if `filename` or `linenum` have any values attached to it, returning false otherwise.

Comment: That doesnt solve my problem. If the user does not pass the optional parameters, I wont have the filename and linenum.

Comment: Then I misunderstood what you wrote. My only suggestion then would be to *strongly **suggest*** to users that they include subroutine/filename and line number into `msg` and use only one `m_log` subroutine.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want them to be passed as compiler macros by the user, you would first have to choose different names for your macros.  `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` are both predefined macros.   These two macros are defined by preprocessor, not passed by the user.  I think that might have cause some confusion.

If you would like to allow users to optionally supply the macros through compiler options, it is probably best to include `#ifdef` directive in your subroutine:

```
subroutine m_log(msg)
  implicit none
  character(len=*) :: msg
  character(len=something) :: file
  integer ::line
  !Initialize file and line to some default value
  file=...
  line=...
#ifdef __KVM_FILE__
   file=__KVM_FILE__
#endif
#ifdef __KVM_LINE__
   line=__KVM_LINE__
#endif
   ...
```

This way the user will always call the subroutine with the same syntax `call m_log(something)`, but the effect will change according to your compilation macros.   Of course, that would also require the user to recompile your code every time they change this macro.  If this is too costly to do, you can set up a subroutine with optional argument (as in Kyle's answer), then enclose `#define` macro in `#ifdef` blocks, and put them into an .h file, and have your user always include that file.  (similar to Vladimir's answer)